# Correlation function for the ground state of simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, correlation-functions

I calculated correlation function $C(t)=\langle x(t)x(0)\rangle$  for ground state of Simple Harmonic Oscillator (SHO) in two different methods. But the results do not match.

First Attempt:

From Heisenberg equations of motion, $$\mathbf{X}(t)=\mathbf{X}(0)\cos(\omega t)+\frac{\mathbf{P}(0)}{m \omega} \sin(\omega t)$$

So, calculated the required terms,

$$\langle 0|\mathbf{X}^2(0)|0\rangle =\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}$$  and

$$\langle 0| \mathbf{P}(0) \mathbf{X}(0) |0\rangle =-~\frac{i \hbar}{2} $$

Using the above two terms and the equation of $\mathbf{X}(t)$ I obtain,
$$\langle 0| \mathbf{X}(t)\mathbf{X}(0)|0\rangle =\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega} \exp(-~i\omega t)$$

This is the required correlation function.

Second Method:

I attempted to solve it using explicit ground state wave function in position basis. In this case, I obtain,

$$\int \psi_0^*(x)\ x^2 \psi_0(x)~ \mathrm{d}x =\frac{\hbar}{2m \omega},$$ which is similar to the first calculation.

Again,

$$\int \psi_0^*(x)\ x (-~i \hbar)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi_0 ~\mathrm{d}x=0,$$ which DOES NOT match with the first method.

And hence, using expression for $X(t)$ like the first method I obtained,

$$\langle X(t)X(0)\rangle =\frac{\hbar}{2m \omega} \cos (\omega t)$$

So method 1 and method 2 does not match. But are not they supposed to match up? I can not figure out where I am making mistake. Any help figuring out the mistakes will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure of your integral for calculating $<PX>$? because it seems to me that you are calculating $<XP>$, remember these do not commute...

Comment: I just checked again. I think I calculated expectation  value of PX.

Comment: Oh, you mean second time. yes, I think so. Let me redo that part.

Comment: Indeed you should obtain the expected result, I did the integral and found $-i\hbar/2$, so check your calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much, got the same answer. Now I am wondering what does this imaginary expectation value means for PX operator? P and X are Hermitian, so this is bugging me that expectation value of PX gives imaginary result.

Comment: The product of two Hermitian operators is not Hermitian itself in general

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That must be true, I also found this out while I was talking with my friend about this. Since, $(PX)\dagger=X\dagger P\dagger =XP$ and $[P,X]=-i\hbar\neq 0$. So I guess it is not surprising that XP or PX has imaginary expectation value in this case.

Comment: Just noticed, initially when I posted the question:  in the second method, I not only calculated $\langle XP \rangle$ instead of $\langle PX \rangle$, but also calculated that  quantity wrong.  That should be $\langle XP \rangle =i \frac{\hbar}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider that in the second case, the wave functions need to carry the time dependence as the operators in Schrödinger-Picture are assumed to be time independent. Thus the equation should look like:

$$
\left<\mathbf{X}(t)\mathbf{X}(0)\right>=\left<x,\ t\right| \mathbf{X}^2\left|x,\ 0 \right>
$$
This however would in position representation with wave-functions reduce to

$$
\int\psi^*\left(x,\ t \right) x^2\psi\left(x,\ 0\right) \mathrm{d} x
$$
and thus the time-dependence from
$$ \psi\left(x,\ t\right)=\psi\left(x,\ 0\right) \mathrm{e}^{-i\omega t}
$$

should remain, giving the same result for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Because you should calculate $\int \Psi^*_0(x)(-i\hbar)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x\Psi_0(x)$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).